# Rails: Save data in two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions

I have a `user` table and a `setting` table with 1-1 relationship. I want to insert some default setting for the newly created user. I am thinking to use `after_create` callback of user. However, I am not sure if this will be transactional. What is the best approach for this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find `after_initialize` callback useful for building the `setting` object for `user` and assigning default `setting`.  Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :setting

  after_initialize :init_user_setting

  private

  def init_user_setting
    # Assign default setting or build
    self.setting = ...
  end
end
```

With this you'll have your complete parent `user` including child `setting`.  When you call `user.save` both `user` and `setting` are saved and both happen inside a transaction.

Comment: At least you came to your senses and avoided a strictly transactional approach. With this implementation you need to take care not to do this every time it's instantiated though, init_user_setting will be set every time. Check if the model is a new model first but you are basically implementing after_create at this point though. And a user should not belong to a setting.

Comment: @CleoR, thanks for the comment.  I'm not sure I quite understand the first sentence, could you please add more to "At least you came to your sense and avoided a strictly transactional approach".  You are right, `after_initialized` is invoked not just when object is created, but that's user's implementation.  Also, thank you for pointing out the `belongs_to` issue in the answer.  I've changed it to `has_one` as per your recommendation!

Comment: Sorry that was meant for the OP! I guess I was kind of angry at the chat we had. He totally disregarded what I was saying but I guess he changed his mind. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @CleoR, no worries at all.  I just wanted to understand more on the "avoided a strictly transactional approach".  No hard feelings, stay cool man! :)

Comment: @CleoR You were angry so you down voted the question? Bravo !! btw, I am the one who decides to choose what answers fits my problem. You cannot force to accept answer in anyway until and unless it is only the correct one. Even if your answer is correct however, it seemed to be alot work just for the sake of answer.

Comment: @nebula No one gives a damn about your question, the only thing I WAS angry about was the effort I put in to help you out and then I got 0 response. But if you wanna write buggy code, thats on you and in the end I got some extra practice. And last I checked there was a negative 2 beside your question bruh, you must not be doing something right

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after_create` callback or observer both. Both will be okay. But You should also set your default values for settings in a initialize method for attribute assignment. Or you can also use user's create method to do same after save call. But it's not a good way. So prefer either call_back or observer.

Answer (score 0):

--UPDATE--

As you start registering new callbacks for your models, they will be queued for execution. This queue will include all your model's validations, the registered callbacks, and the database operation to be executed.

The whole callback chain is wrapped in a transaction. If any before callback method returns exactly false or raises an exception, the execution chain gets halted and a ROLLBACK is issued; after callbacks can only accomplish that by raising an exception.

After setting an attribute to false at the end of a before_save callback, I could not for the life of me figure out why the object would never save! Before callbacks must return truthy values or it will rollback.

--Previous--

You need to do something like this. This is my default approach for anything short of dealing with currency.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :setting
  after_create :setup_user

  private

  def setup_user
    user_settings = self.setting.new
    user_settings.attr1 = foo1
    user_settings.attr2 = foo2
    user_settings.save
  end

end

class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Ideally you would put validations on the user and make it so that if a user is valid a setting is also valid. But if you don't do that, you need to use

```
if !user_settings.save
  self.destroy
end
```

For where to put the default values,if the setting default values depend on the user, stick them in the setup_user method. If the setting default values doesn't care about the user, stick them in a before_save or before_validation method on the setting. With regards to the user, you need to use an after_create method for the case where a user doesn't validate, you want those callbacks to only fire if a user is successfully created. You don't want to user after_validation because the user would not have been created and if the setting contains a foreign id to the user that is not yet created, for an instant your database will be inconsistent.

Transaction based approach

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :setting
  after_commit :setup_user, on: [:create]
  after_rollback :undo_user, on: [:create]

  private

  def setup_user
    user_settings = self.setting.new
    user_settings.attr1 = foo1
    user_settings.attr2 = foo2
    user_settings.save!
  end

  def undo_user
    #The users settings didn't save so roll back the user
    self.destroy
  end

end

class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

end
```

To put it in the same transaction you need to use after_commit and after_rollback. Using .save! will throw an exception and trigger after_rollback. You will not have a user without the setting.

Comment: but will this be in single transaction?

Comment: I'm looking it up here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html as we speak and here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: It appears you need to use the after_commit callback instead of after_create. It ensures that they will be in the same transaction.

Comment: That should work, that's how they say to do it in the guides. Theres your commit and your rollback. Check out the transaction section here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: Why do you want to put user and setting inside the same transaction?

Comment: because new user will have default settings. Its all or none.

Comment: If you put your user through validation, you can guarantee the information is formatted correctly when you use the user's information to setup the default settings. With proper testing you won't have this problem. It seems like a lot of extra work.

Comment: Anyway the after_commit and after_rollback callbacks are what you want to use.

Comment: Hmm. Putting user through validation won't guarantee the data to be consistent. It has to be transactional if you want the data to be consistent. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: If you ensure a setting is valid if a user is valid. And a user is only valid if it meets certain conditions, then the data will always be consistent. If you're worried about the case where for some reason the database has a fault and the setting doesn't save for some reason not your own, I would call that prematurely optimizing and extra work. But there are docs surrounding Rails Transactions if they are needed. I would optionally put setting.save as the argument for an if statement and handle any deconstruction work there. They all ensure there is no user if there is no setting. And no probs

Comment: I updated my answer to do what you want, it for sure works. The only thing I would say is that using this approach for something like this makes it hard to display to the user why they couldn't register. Imagine if you have multiple things you want to create and they all get rolled back because 1 object didn't save. What do you tell the user?

Comment: You need to provide feedback if it doesn't work or accept an answer. In the future when other people view this page they need to know what works.